# Best method to store and read data from a cloud source in Android?

Tags: android, cloud, storage

The situation: I have many real life locations with specific information associated with them, and updated frequently. I am unsure of how to store this information for use in an android application.

My original thought was storing the data on some server/cloud source/database, reading from the server from each Activity in the app to make sure the info is up to date, and update the server with any changes that may or may not have been made.

For example: there are 200 people inside the library, one person leaves. 
So we would read the number of people from the server, display this on the app, person leaves, subtract one, send the new number back to the server.

Would this be an incorrect approach? I'm fairly new to Android in general, and I really have no experience on how to approach this type of situation, what services to use, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using [Parse](https://www.parse.com/), its a pretty sweet way to power the backend, and their website is very detailed in explaining how to use it.